# Why this method call can not be converted into lambda?

Tags: android, lambda, retrolambda

Consider the following code:

```
recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                //some code here
            }
        });
```

Why can it not be translated into this:

```
recyclerView.addOnScrollListener((recyclerView, dx, dy) -> {
    // some code here
});
```

I'm using `retrolambda` in AndroidStudio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `RecyclerView.OnScrollListener` is an abstract class and actually has more methods than just `onScrolled`.

Comment: @HamedMomeni I think everyone hits the same problem at least once when they start working with lambdas :)